# MySQL ORDER BY field created by GROUP_CONCAT()

Tags: mysql, sql

Input two table, `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`

```
 TABLE_A       TABLE_B
 A_ID |   A    A_ID |  B        
    1 |   a       1 |  b
    2 |  a1       1 | b1
    3 |  a2       2 | b2
```

Expecting Output `TABLE C`

```
 TABLE_C
 A_ID |  A | C
    3 | a2 | NULL  <--- NULL if no matched A_ID in TABLE B
    1 |  a | b,b1  <--- Concat all rows in TABLE B with ','
    2 | a1 | b2
```

Following code can almost give the above `TABLE_C` except I want to sort field `C` with `NULL` first then `DESC`. `ORDER BY C IS NULL DESC` does not seems to work. **Note that if `C` is `NULL` TABLE_C will order by A_ID regardless the value in field  `C`.**

```
SELECT 
  A1.A_ID, 
  A1.A, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(B1.B SEPARATOR ',') as 'C'
FROM `TABLE_A` A1 
  LEFT JOIN `TABLE_B` B1 
  ON A1.A_ID=B1.A_ID 
GROUP BY A1.A_ID, A1.A;
```

Following SQL gives error.

```
SELECT 
  A1.A_ID, 
  A1.A, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(B1.B SEPARATOR ',') as 'C'
FROM `TABLE_A` A1 
  LEFT JOIN `TABLE_B` B1 
  ON A1.A_ID=B1.A_ID 
GROUP BY A1.A_ID, A1.A
ORDER BY C IS NULL DESC, A1.A_ID; <--- Order by C with NULL failed.
```

Reference 'C' not supported (reference to group function)

Comment: Kindly use the answer i posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ORDER BY Null values first and then by A1.A_ID use:

```
SELECT A1.A_ID, A1.A, GROUP_CONCAT(B1.B SEPARATOR ',') as C 
FROM `TABLE_A` A1 
LEFT JOIN `TABLE_B` B1 ON A1.A_ID=B1.A_ID 
GROUP BY A1.A_ID, A1.A 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(B1.B SEPARATOR ',') IS NULL then GROUP_CONCAT(B1.B SEPARATOR ',') ELSE A1.A_ID END) ;
```

*and regarding the error `Reference 'C' not supported (reference to group function)` you should be ordering by `'C'` ie*

```
ORDER BY 'C' IS NULL DESC, A1.A_ID;
```

and not `ORDER BY C IS NULL DESC, A1.A_ID;`

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `Is Null` in order by

```
SELECT 
  A1.A_ID, 
  A1.A, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(B1.B SEPARATOR ',') as 'C'
FROM `TABLE_A` A1 
  LEFT JOIN `TABLE_B` B1 
  ON A1.A_ID=B1.A_ID 
GROUP BY A1.A_ID, A1.A
ORDER BY C, A1.A_ID DESC
```

Comment: Noted that I want all `C` with `NULL` to list out first, then order by `A1.A_ID`. I want **no** sort on `C` if there is value in `C`. Your answer will sort every values in `C` not only `NULL`.